# Mapping a specific set of keypresses to other keypresses using AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, touchpad

I'm trying to map the 3 finger swipe gesture on my touchpad to Ctrl+Win+Left or Ctrl+Win+Right (switching between virtual desktops). Here are the keys pressed when I swipe left:

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
-------------------------------------------------------
A2  01D a   d   1.08    LControl        
A4  038 a   d   0.00    LAlt            
09  00F a   d   0.00    Tab             
09  00F a   u   0.00    Tab             
A4  038 a   u   0.00    LAlt            
A2  01D a   u   0.00    LControl        
0D  01C a   d   0.20    Enter           Task Switching
0D  01C a   u   0.00    Enter
```

And when I swipe right:

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
-----------------------------------------------
A2  01D a   d   1.69    LControl        
A4  038 a   d   0.00    LAlt            
A0  02A a   d   0.00    LShift          
09  00F a   d   0.00    Tab             
09  00F a   u   0.00    Tab             
A0  02A a   u   0.01    LShift          
A4  038 a   u   0.00    LAlt            
A2  01D a   u   0.00    LControl        
0D  01C a   d   0.16    Enter           Task Switching
0D  01C a   u   0.00    Enter
```

How do I map these to Ctrl+Win+Left and Ctrl+Win+Right?

I tried this `Alt & Ctrl & Enter & Tab::Send test`, but it's saying that it's an invalid program.

In case it's relevant, I'm using Windows 10 on a Thinkpad L440 with Synaptics touchpad driver.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Enter` a selection based on a dialog?  If so then it wouldn't be sent as a part of the automation.

I believe the following code should generate the keylogs listed, but not tested...

```
^#Left::
    SendInput ^!{Tab}
    SendInput {Enter}    ; use only if needed
Return

^#Right::
    SendInput ^!+{Tab}
    SendInput {Enter}
 Return
```

Look in the help files for the Key List and the list of modifers

```
^ = Control
! = Alt
# = Win
+ = Shift
```

Also, if this is a new Windows 10 specific feature then the keys may not work exactly as desired and you may need to use `AltTab` and `ShiftAltTab` with a Control key modifier.  On previous versions of windows these combinations can have special behavior so there is a special case (see `AltTab` in help files).

You could also try the keystrokes manually to see if it does what the swipe does.  If trying it manually works, then the AutoHotkey keystrokes should work without needing to use something special.  I.e., try pressing Ctrl+Alt+Tab (down, up) and then Enter (down, up), or pressing Shift+Ctrl+Alt+Tab (down, up) and then Enter (down, up).  That's what the keystroke logs indicate with the `d` and `u` characters.

**EDIT...**

Based on the subsequent follow-up post, I see why the code above is functionally backwards (I didn't fully understand the question initially, but I will leave my original post above as-is).

In answer to the question of "a better method", the code posted already looks great and is very straightforward (no reason to change it really)--two possible style differences below are just to show some possible variations in answer to the question--code that might be 'cleaner' using built-in hotkey variables and ternary operators.

First up, hotkey variables `A_ThisHotkey` and `A_PriorHotkey` can be used to detect the present hotkey and last hotkey that fired.  This lets you simplify the variable assignment by getting rid of the variable used for tracking which one triggered last.  The hotkey definitions still need to be in place so the event is captured and discarded, but they don't need to do anything now other than return.

```
^!Tab::return
^!+Tab::return
$Enter::
    if (A_PriorHotkey="^!Tab") {
        SendInput ^#{Left}
    } else if (A_PriorHotkey="^!+Tab") {
        SendInput ^#{Right}
    } else
        SendInput {Enter}
return
```

You can see how this is looking a little simpler and less spread out already.

The final variation is to use a ternary operator now to effectively do an If-Then-Else statement and combine everything into a single statement:

```
^!Tab::Return
^!+Tab::Return
$Enter::SendInput % (A_PriorHotkey="^!Tab") ? "^#{Left}" : (A_PriorHotkey="^!+Tab") ? "^#{Right}" : "{Enter}"       ; Final 'Else' Statement
```

Down to three lines of code, but not the most readable.

Making use of one final AutoHotkey allowance, the single line can be split using automatic continuation operators when the lines start with a comma, colon or period for stringing things together... this allows the use of logical line breaks, and makes for a pretty clear If-Then-Else structure with the ternary `?` operator, without having a bunch of If-Then-Else-Else-Else statements.

The final code would look something like this...

```
^!Tab::return
^!+Tab::return
$Enter::SendInput % (A_PriorHotkey="^!Tab")  ? "^#{Left}"
                  : (A_PriorHotkey="^!+Tab") ? "^#{Right}"
                  : "{Enter}"    ; Final 'Else' Statement
```

Or with alternative spacing on the final 'Else' to keep all of the Send arguments aligned vertically...

```
^!Tab::return
^!+Tab::return
$Enter::SendInput % (A_PriorHotkey="^!Tab")  ? "^#{Left}"
                  : (A_PriorHotkey="^!+Tab") ? "^#{Right}"
                                             : "{Enter}"      ; Final 'Else' Statement
```

One final side note--I can't actually test the code excerpts above, even though I believe they should work as listed. They are all just style updates as noted (i.e., updates to the follow-up code posted already by the user who posted the original question)--there are ultimately no functional differences, just a few features that AutoHotkey offers if you continue developing.

Comment: Thanks for this! I think you have the inputs and outputs backwards though. The Control+Alt+Tab+Enter is the input (produced by the swipe). I want the output to be `^#Left` or `^#Right`.

Comment: I figured it out! Can you take a look at my answer and see if there's anything that can be improved?

Answer (score 0):

After an hour or two of tinkering, I figured it out:

```
swipeDirection := ""

^!Tab::
    swipeDirection := "L"
return

^!+Tab::
    swipeDirection := "R"
return

$Enter::
    if (not swipeDirection) {
        SendInput {Enter}
    } else if (swipeDirection = "L") {
        SendInput ^#{Left}
    } else if (swipeDirection = "R") {
        SendInput ^#{Right}
    }
    swipeDirection := ""
return
```

Let me know if there's a better method!

Edit:

I wrote about this on my blog: https://www.wptutor.io/misc/windows-virtual-desktop-swipe-gestures